# How can i add form elements through a button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text-files

I am programming a quiz maker input form which is responsive to the users desired number of questions. These quizzes will be grouped by the students year and class, set up through a responsive menu read from a text file. This text file will be added to by the user by creating 'Topics' in the quizzes, and grouping them as such. I want to create a button at the bottom of the form which copies the input fields for 'question', 'answer1', 'answer2' and 'answer3'.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz Form</title>
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“TRYstyle.css”>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Quiz form</h3>

<table>
  <form onSubmit=“WriteToFile(this.txt)>
    <tr>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>
    <select name="Year" id="schoolyear">
    <option value="1">7</option>
    <option value="2">8</option>
    <option value="3">9</option>
    <option value="4">10</option>
    <option value="5">11</option>
    <option value="6">12</option>
    <option value="7">13</option>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>
    <select name=“group” id=“group”>
    <option value="1">H</option>
    <option value="2">E</option>
    <option value="3">A</option>
    <option value="4">R</option>
    <option value="5">T</option>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Topic</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Topic” name=“topic” id=“topic”  maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Title” name=“title” id=“title”  maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Question</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Question” name=“question” id=“question” maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Answer</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer1” id=“answer1” maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Answer</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer2” id=“answer2” maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Answer</td>
      <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer3” id=“answer3” maxlength=“200”/></td>
    </tr>

    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
  </form>
</table>


<script>
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    set s   = fso.CreateTextFile(“using theseee/this.txt", True);

    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var group = document.getElementById('group');
    var topic = document.getElementById('topic');
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var question  = document.getElementById('question');
    var option1 = document.getElementById('answer1');
    var option2 = document.getElementById('answer2');
    var option3 = document.getElementById('answer3');

    s.writeline("Title: " + title);
      s.writeline("Question: " + question);
        s.writeline("Option1: " + answer1);
          s.writeline(“Option2: " + answer2);
            s.writeline("Option3: " + answer3);

              s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, to store the various 'topics', would I need to create a text file dedicated to these considering the menu is responsive to this? Or can i read the first line, lets say, from each text file relevant and store them in the menu? What is the best way to go about doing this?
I am sorry if this seems very low level, but I am trying very hard to get the hang of all of this as I am new to it all.

Comment: Hey Joe, as it stands now this question looks a bit too broad. I understand what you are trying to accomplish as a whole, but you need to narrow down your question to one specific problem you are having.

Comment: I am aiming to create a button which duplicates the Question input box and the 3 different Answer input boxes, by grouping them, and adding them to the end of my form. The idea is to ideally have as many questions as the user would want, but i am unsure on how to do this

Comment: Your code is going to encounter some errors with all those curly quotes. `“` and `”` are typographic quotes and are not interpreted the same as `"` by browsers. I would recommend against coding in a word processor. A code editor or even a simple unformatted notepad would prevent these error creating characters.